# Dropbox keeps having me log back in

Tags: 12.10, restart, dropbox

Each time I boot up Ubuntu, Dropbox asks me to log back and then tells me that I have linked to this computer before, which I have. I am running Ubuntu 12.10 off of a live USB. Dropbox is the only other program that does this (asking me to log back in and not remembering my credentials). Help?